# JS plugin to highlight & run javascript in the page

Tags: javascript, edit, highlight, code-snippets

I'm writing the documentation of a JS lib and I frequently insert code examples. What I would like is to allow users to edit et execute these examples (with a RUN button for example).

Does someone know a light js plugin which could do that? (with code highlighter).

Edit: just something to run JS code, like a very simple web console, no need to edit CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Codepen allows you to embed code samples with syntax highlighting, and an ability to run them in a sandboxed environment.

Here's an example code snippet for embedding (so this answer doesn't get flagged for not having code, but really the docs are extremely easy to read):

```
<p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="ClnAe" data-user="afkatja" data-default-tab="result" class='codepen'>See the Pen <a href='http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ClnAe'>ClnAe</a> by Katja Hollar (<a href='http://codepen.io/afkatja'>@afkatja</a>) on <a href='http://codepen.io'>CodePen</a></p>
```

[Here's a blog post](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens/) from Codepen with more details on how-to.

[Here's an example of a blog post](http://varun.ca/parallax) that uses an embedded Codepen.

Edit: Just realized you wanted the code samples to be editable. I'm afraid that's a Codepen PRO feature as documented in [this blog post](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/pro-features/editable-embeds/). So still an option perhaps, but there may be alternatives that do it for free.